# Defining the 5 and 95 and percentiles in group_by

Tags: r, dplyr, histogram

I am looking for a way to define the values of a column into percentiles. The data looks similar to this but with more complex values of column E:

`data.frame(Date=c(rep("2010-01-31", 60), rep("2010-02-28", 60)), E=c(rep(1:20, 6)))`

The data should be grouped around the data variable. The brackets are to be used to create a histogram like the one attached below. If you could kindly also help me with a code that does that, it would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something in line of:

```
      df <- df %>%
           group_by(Date) %>% 
           mutate(first = quantile(E,0.5),
                  second = quantile(E,0.95))
```

With data.table:

```
setDT(df)
df[,c("first","second") := list(quantile(E,0.5),quantile(E,0.95)), by = "Date"]
```

Comment: Not exactly. I would like all percentiles between 5% and 95% in one column. For example, if the value is in the 95 percentile then it would have the value 19. This would allow me to plot the average return of all the different percentiles against each other over time. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I probably need an ifelse statement similar to this expanded to include all percentiles.

CombData <- CombData %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate(E_P = ifelse(E